# Why some people can't see color in memory or dreams

Tags: memory, dreams, color

Some of my friends told me they never see color in memory or dreams, is this some kind of symptom? Does it have a name in psychology?

I did some search on internet, but seems most pages did not explain why this happens.

Some of them suggest it might related with black white TV or traumatic events, but this seems not the case for people that never see color in memory.

Could someone explain this, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [12 percent of our dreams are in black and white?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/12-percent-of-our-dreams-are-in-black-and-white)